# Can $\sec x $ be not only $1/\cos x $ but also $\cos(1/x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

The question was finding the trig value of $\sec^{-1}(-2/\sqrt{3})$. And, my teacher solved it making it to $\cos^{-1}(-\sqrt{3}/2)$. Is that possible? Can $\sec^{-1} x$  be $\cos^{-1}(1/x)$? ( I'm sorry I'm not handy with the signs. The $-1$ means the inverse function and the things next to it are the angles.)

Comment: Sec(x) = 1 / cos(x), so arcsec(x) = arcos(1/x).

Comment: Do you understand what $\cos^{-1} x$ means?  It's not $\frac{1}{\cos x}$

Comment: I know. But I thought Sec^-1(x) would be 1/ cos^-1(x) not cos^-1(1/x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sec^{-1}(x)=y$

Then $\sec(y)=x$

Which means $\cos(y)=\frac{1}{x}$

So $y=\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$

Therefore $\sec^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: but then is sec^-1(x)=1/cos^-1(x)? Isn't that the definition?

Comment: That's false and can be shown with a counterexample

Comment: than what's that counterexample

Comment: There are numerous counterexamples but here is one such counterexample:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arcsec(.2)%3D1%2Farccos(.2)

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the $\sec^{-1}x = \cos^{-1}\left(1/x\right)$.  Let $\theta$ be the $\sec^{-1}x$.  That means $\sec \theta  = x$.  What then is the cosine?  It's $1/x$

Comment: thanks a lot!  .( and for editing lol)